# Why is "ни" used in a phrase "кто бы то ни был"?

Tags: словоупотребление, phrase

I have found out that there is a phrase, which has a meaning of something like "whoever it was" - "кто бы то ни был". Why is "ни" used instead of "не"?

Comment: "Кого бы я не спрашивал" is not even a phrase, eh?

Comment: It is a phrase - "Кого бы я не спрашивал о песнях про Байкал, люди помнят лишь две песни - «Славное море - священный Байкал» и «По диким степям Забайкалья»". http://nature.baikal.ru/forum/tread.shtml?id=1423

Comment: @L_Pav it is a typo in this phrase.

Comment: @L_Pav it should be "ни" there.

Comment: Yup, just realised that)

Comment: Just remember it. It is heavily used

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"ни"* is the amplifying particle, *"не"* is the negative particle.

There are no negation in phrase *"whoever it was"* and so particle *"ни"* used.

Comment: Ни is also a negative particle in most cases: никто, ни один, ни ел, ни пил.

Comment: @SergeySlepov nope. Try to write whole sentence with one of this cases.

Comment: Easy-peasy :) Кто ни ел, ни пил? Никто!

Comment: @SergeySlepov *"Кто **не** ел, **не** пил? Никто [**не** ел, **не** пил]!"*

Comment: OK, bad example, I agree. How about this one? "В кармане ни гроша" - is that a positive sentence?

Comment: @SergeySlepov that sentence has omited predicate: *"В кармане ни гроша [**нет**]"*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70515/discussion-between-sergey-slepov-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 5):

This is because the particle "ни" has a different meaning than the particle "не". In affirmative sentences in conjunction with the pronoun or interrogative words, "ни" means a true statement in any options:

Кого бы я **ни спрашивал**, все говорили, что **не знают** его.

Try to change "ни" to "не". The sense of the statement will change:

Кого бы я не спрашивал, все говорили, что не знают его. - I asked
    nobody, nobody knows him. 
Кого бы я ни спрашивал, все говорили, что
    не знают его. - I asked everyone, nobody knows him.

Answer (score 1):

This word (looking different now and often mistook for "не" - "not") is a remnant of some old slavonic laguage. Standing in this context for the word "ever" usually going in company with "be" - "быть".
Like in:
*whoever* that *be* - *кто* бы это там *ни был*
whenever it happens - *когда* бы это *ни* происходило
*weherever* it *is* - *где* бы это *ни было*
Deep research should be made to find what word to this particle relates, in old slavonic. Because it is only orthographic dictionaries now are instructing how to write russian words with "не/ни". No any reference to language history. So few (if someone at all) people can give answer about the "ни" particle and why it is written that way.

Answer (score 0):

The particle **не** is normally used for negation:

- Не пойман - не вор. ([If one is] not caught, [then one is] not a thief.)

As for **ни**, there are actually two homonymic particles, one used for negation (on its own or with **не**):

- Ни рыба, ни мясо
- Ни себе, ни людям
- Ни шагу назад! (Not a step backwards!)
- Никто не забыт, ничто не забыто. (No one is forgotten, nothing is forgotten.)

The other meaning "any", "every", "whichever":

- Где бы я ни был (wherever I am), куда б я ни шёл (wherever I go), etc.
- Куда-нибудь (somewhere), что-нибудь (something), etc (here **ни** merged with **будь** but retained the meaning).
- Что ни на есть, какой ни на есть, etc.
- Куда ни глянь (wherever you look), как ни старайся (however hard you try), etc.
- Что ни день, то новости. (Every day there's news.) Etc.

It is this **ни** that appears in **кто бы то ни был** ('whoever it may be').

Source: [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLGcD1ACbZo&t=3397s) by A. A. Zalizniak. The link points to 56:37 where the discussion of **ни** (meaning "any") begins but I recommend watching the whole lecture.

Comment: *"Он ни ел, ни пил"* is a mistake; modern Russian rules requires two *"не"* particles in this case.

Comment: That guy has worse Russian than me. Uhh, uhh, uhhhh--god, it drove me nuts. Basically, НИ was and still kind of is NOR, NEITHER. And-- кто бы он ни был = who (he, she, it) would neither (nor) be..., = it does not matter who.... Thanks for finally clearing this up for me. good answer.

Comment: Где бы я ни был--where would I (not, neither) be,...--Where (ever) I would not be = Be I here, be I there--nor there, nor here/ neither here nor there--it does not matter, all are the same.

Comment: что ни говори--what (ever) you are saying, or not saying--what you neither say,... it makes no difference. In a word--Он не ел, ни пил--the second part ,ни ... can be used alone to cover all the bases. Как бы то ни было--How that would be, or not be... all are the same.